# Unique email with each type of user in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I want to register many user with the same email but different type

For example
1@gmail.com type 1
2@gmail.com type 2

the email will unique with type is the condition. How can I write the rule if the type is not an input

This is my code validator but it's failed because the type is not an input

```
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|min:3',
            'password' => 'required',
            'phone' => 'required|unique:users|numeric',
            'email' => [
                'required',
                'email',
                Rule::unique('users')
                    ->where('type', $this->type)
            ]
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        $validate = [
            'name' => 'required|min:3',
            'password' => 'required',
            'phone' => 'required|unique:users|numeric',
            'plan_name' => [
                'required',
                'email',
                Rule::unique('users')->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
                  return $query->where('type', $request->type);  
                })                    
            ]
        ];

        $this->validate($request, $validate);
```

I think this will help